# Aiogram загрузка файла

Tags: telebot, aiogram, бот

Пытаюсь загрузить документ pdf через хендлер следующим образом

```
await message.document.download()
```

Выходит ошибка aiogram.utils.exceptions.fileistoobig
Файл весит 28 мб, можно ли обойти это?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать Local Bot API Server. Там нет ограничений на размер файлов
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Цитировать что? Bot API Telegram? В моем ответе исчерпывающая информация на вопрос автора, взятая по этой ссылке. Кроме того, если источник будет закрыт или недоступен, то смысла в вопросе и ответе уже не будет никакого